# Facebook connect not working (SDK 3)

Tags: android, facebook, debugging, facebook-login

In my app I'm using Facebook SDK and everything works fine when I'm debugging it, after signing it I can't log in to facebook account on every telephone (works on Galaxy GIO and s2 not working on Xperia Arc S). After clicking log in it shows: could not find the page fbconnect:/success/#access_token=[access-token] . I have provided both keyhashes for debug.keystore and mine own keystore. I thought i found a solution: [here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108397/android-facebook-connect-not-working-in-release-build) but it's not working for me, or maybe I'm doing something wrong with it.

Due to this link I have to add following code to my proguard-project.txt:

```
# need this for Facebook SDK
-keepattributes Signature

-dontwarn com.facebook.**
-dontwarn com.parse.**

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
```

But as I said it's not working or maybe I have to replace stars above with some code (I'm a newbie) ? Thanks for help

Comment: I am having the same problem. Please post your answer if you were able to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried updating the facebook app and the problem was solved.

Maybe you have an old version installed too. Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I think that what happened was that the older version of the facebook app did not register the fbconnect scheme and success host in the manifest, so it was not handling requests that went to that url.

Comment: is it required to be always having the latest facebook app? the size of the newest one is just too damn high!