# I got this error for first attempt to login facebook.How can solve this?

Tags: android, proguard, android-facebook

I searched very much but I did not see the real solution. Somebody says use ex facebook sdk , is it the real solution?(I use facebook 3.6 but somebody says on stackoverflow use 3.2)
I use proguard,

```
com.facebook.aq: com.facebook.c.f got an unexpected method signature: public abstract java.lang.Object com.facebook.c.c.e()
at com.facebook.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.c.f.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy0.e(Native Method)
at com.facebook.b.al.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.b.al.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.f.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: What is _ex facebook sdk_?

Comment: I use facebook 3.6 but somebody says on stackoverflow use 3.2

Comment: I think you go wrong way. always used Latest SDK and your logcat said that your SDK not contain some classes that you import into your java class

Comment: Simple solution already provided in older post. [Click here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760581/android-proguard-settings-for-facebook

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest **`facebook sdk`** and you should login with using 
**app_secret** like this :

```
  String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", app_secret );
        Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
    mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
```

(I think this solves your problem bacause you have a problem just the first login )

Comment: thank you the answer is I forget the set app_secret, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There are some settings that you need to set for proguard.

The number of posts can explain the right way.

Check them out.

Some are listed below:-

1) **Using Signature** - [**Error-on-using-proguard-with-android-facebook-sdk-3-0**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538070/error-on-using-proguard-with-android-facebook-sdk-3-0).

So you use -

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

2) **[Android-facebook-connect-not-working-in-release-build.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108397/android-facebook-connect-not-working-in-release-build)-**

So, issue can be with your proguard configuration settings:

- *proguard.cfg (ERROR)*

> -keep class com.facebook.android.*
>
> ```
> -keepclassmembers public class com.facebook.android.Facebook { 
>
>     public static final *; 
> }
> ```

- *proguard.cfg (WITHOUT ERROR)*

> -keep class com.facebook.android.*
>
> ```
> -keep class android.webkit.WebViewClient
>
> -keep class * extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.webkit.WebViewClient { 
>     <methods>; 
> }
> ```

3) **[Android ProGuard settings for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760581/android-proguard-settings-for-facebook)**

Comment: thanks for asnwer, I already do these things but the result is same